# Why is std::cerr mixing up console outputs in ROS C++

Tags: c++, ros

I am printing out a line of code using std::cerr, it looks like below

```
act_pub_timer_ = nh_.createTimer(ros::Duration(1.0/100.0), &func1, this);
int myvar = 0;

int func1()
{
   std::cerr << "\nThe value is : " << myvar << "\n";
   myvar ++;
}
```

The code prints out the correct output for a while which goes like

```
The value is 0
The value is 1
```

and so forth

After some time it starts mixing up the output. It prints

```
The value is
The value is 01
```

As can be seen in the first part it did not append 0 but it appended it on the second part.

Comment: Possibly one call to `func1` hasn't completed before the next one comes along.

Comment: Great how can I make sure that `func1` completes execution before it is called again

Comment: what is `this` ? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Output to consoles is generally comparably slow.

Comment: "_how can I make sure that func1 completes execution before it is called again_" - One way is to do it in serial.

Comment: Instead of using recurring timers, use one-shot timers. And let the timer-callback function create its next one-shot timer, just before the function returns.

Comment: Some great ideas for solving the problem, here. Let's see them in the answer section!

Comment: Also you may wish to read http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning in more detail and consider whether your current callback queue model is right for you. You didn't tell us what it is (post  a  [mcve]  on  SO  questions!!!) so I couldn't really say more.

Comment: Honestly, i don't believe my idea will work, but let's give it a try: Use `std::cerr << "\nThe value is : " << myvar << "\n" << std::flush;` to force the cout << operator to be a bit more atomic. It seems that the `myvar` variable was missing in the first output but added to the second one. So it seems the << operator before the variable was interupted. It is just a guess, but it might work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mutex lock

http://wiki.ros.org/remote_mutex

This will make sure that one instance of function finishes before the next starts and overlapping will not happen.